# Ignored characters in Where-Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following problem:

I try to select everything below `'G-'` but as it seems it ignores the - and selects everything with G and below.

```
select * from tableA where ColumnA > 'G-' order by ColumnA
```

If i use `> 'G-T'` it ignores the `'-'` totally, giving me things like `'GT...'`

Comment: Would be nice if you read [ask], but in short, show your input, show your code, show your output, explain why it's not what you want, and show your requested output

Comment: If you want to select everything *below* 'G-', why are you using the `Larger-Than` Operator? Is this your actual query?

Comment: When using `> 'G-T'` I would expect `'G-Z'` to be in the results and `'G-A'` not. I wouldn't have any expectations regarding `'GZ'` or `'G#Z'` or `'G Z'`, though. Who knows what SQL-Server regards lower or higher from `'-'`, `'Z'`, `'#'`, and `' '`? And who cares? Isn't this even collation-dependent? How come, you have certain expectations? What makes you expect `'GT'` to be higher or lower than `'G-T'`? It looks like you are trying to solve some problem with the wrong approach - maybe even a wrong data model.

Answer (score 2):

The sorting value of `'-'` is lower than the one from `'T'` so `'G-'` is lower than `'GT'`.

So

```
select * from tableA where ColumnA > 'G-' order by ColumnA
```

will return `'GT'`, but

```
select * from tableA where ColumnA < 'G-' order by ColumnA
```

won't. `'-'` is not ignored, it's just lower than `'T'`.

Of course, the same goes if you try using `ColumnA > 'G-T'`, for the same reasons.

If you want to select everything that starts with `'G-'`, use `LIKE`:

```
select * from tableA where ColumnA LIKE 'G-%' order by ColumnA
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/932f7/2) showing all the results.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and that really makes sence but i looked at my select and this is what keeps me wondering:

select * from TableA where ColumnA > 'G-' order by ColumnA

gives me Results like 'G 22', 'G-A', so is it even lower than a Space? Is there a table where i can see this kind of lower/higher - Values?

Comment: Weird, it doesn't return 'G 22' on [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca0e1/1). Maybe your space is not a regular space, but some other non printable character. I don't really know which value is used for sorting, I guess it can be Unicode value or some other, depending on the collation.

Comment: @Mr.Vetter Basically, that's what a collation is - rules for interpreting the binary data used to store text. For example, in a case-insensitive colation, `A` and `a` would be equal, but in a case-sensitive one, they would not. First you need to find out what collation you are using, and then use that collation's rules to understand what's going on. Then it shouldn't be too hard to get the results you want - maybe something like `A like '.-%' and A > 'G'` will work for you?

Comment: I use the Collation Latin1_General_CI_AS, which other should i try ?

Comment: @Mr.Vetter Yup, that explains it - if you force that collation in X.L.Ant's fiddle, it also shows `G 22`. See this chart - http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0409.1252.Latin1_General_CI_AS.html It shows the "proper" ordering of the "characters". Interestingly, doing the `order by` in this collation results in `G-, G 22, GT, G-T` - the rules of text ordering and comparison are a lot more complex than you might think, and depend heavily on the collation used. If you want something a bit more predictable, `Latin1_General_BIN` might be more appropriate - provided the column is indeed an ID.

Comment: Yes you are correct thank you for the informations! 

One thing though: i tried the collation you mentioned and it alters the result/orders quite a bit.

My first row now is '-ABC', how is this greater than 'G-' ? (all other rows are 'G...'/'G-...')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your collation - you're using a text collation for ordering of what appears to be non-text data. Given your requirements, I'd suggest using Latin1_General_Binary as the column's collation - provided the data really *is* strongly formed, and not "human-like".

For example, for values of

```
G-
G 22
G-T
GT
```

the ordering in Latin1_General_Binary is

```
G 22
G-
G-T
GT
```

In Latin1_General_CI_AS it's

```
G-
G 22
GT
G-T
```

The basic reason for this is that `-` is considered an ignorable character; the purpose of this is to sort `co-operation` near `cooperation`, for example. This is very important for text sorting - for example, in czech, `Ch` is considered a single letter (after `H`, not `C`), so even though it's written as two separate letters in Latin2, the sorting must take this into account.

`GT` being larger than `G-T` is somewhat unavoidable - symbols and control characters tend to be located before numbers and letters in most collations. How much this bothers you depends on your requirements - if the form `A-B` is something special for you, you could use something like this:

```
where A like `.-%` and A > `G-`
```

If it's not a problem to you, though, I'd avoid forcing a non-trivial ordering - your indices will thank you.

If the pattern isn't as simple as this, you're basically in a world of hurt - SQL databases rely quite a bit on having normalised data, and by this point, your ID no longer is a single logical column. Separating it into multiple columns might work, depending again on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'like' operator.

```
Create table vstab
(
col1 varchar(100)
)

insert into vstab
Select 'G-1'

insert into vstab
Select 'G-2'

insert into vstab
Select 'G1'

insert into vstab
Select 'G2'

Select * from VSTab where col1 like 'G-%' order by col1
```